# How to split compound column like ROW, ARRAY?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have same problem with this stopped thread.

http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-sql@postgresql.org/msg28070.html

**QUERY-1**

```
SELECT 
r.id,
(
        SELECT 
        rl.reminder_header,
        rl.reminder_footer
        FROM reminder_levels AS rl
        WHERE rl.lookup =
        (
                SELECT MAX(reminder_level_lookup) 
                FROM reminders
                WHERE customer_id = r.customer_id
        )
)
FROM reminders AS r
```

Postgresql replied that:
ERROR: subquery must return only one column

**QUERY-2**

```
SELECT 
r.id,
(
        SELECT 
        rl.reminder_header
        FROM reminder_levels AS rl
        WHERE rl.lookup =
        (
                SELECT MAX(reminder_level_lookup) 
                FROM reminders
                WHERE customer_id = r.customer_id
        )
) AS reminder_header,
(
        SELECT 
        rl.reminder_footer
        FROM reminder_levels AS rl
        WHERE rl.lookup =
        (
                SELECT MAX(reminder_level_lookup) 
                FROM reminders
                WHERE customer_id = r.customer_id
        )
) AS reminder_footer
FROM reminders AS r
```

```
id  |  reminder_header  |  reminder_footer
----+-------------------+--------------------
1   |  hogehoge         |  fugafuga
```

... which works, but runs twice the same subselect block.
This makes performance kill.
(but, this result table is what I want.)

**QUERY-3**

```
SELECT 
r.id,
(
        SELECT 
        ROW(rl.reminder_header, rl.reminder_header)
        FROM reminder_levels AS rl
        WHERE rl.lookup =
        (
                SELECT MAX(reminder_level_lookup) 
                FROM reminders
                WHERE customer_id = r.customer_id
        )
) AS rec
FROM reminders AS r
```

```
id  |  rec
----+----------------------
1   |  (hogehoge, fugafuga)
```

... which works, but column 'rec' is compound.

How to split this 'rec' to reminder_header and reminder_footer, 
like Query-2.

There is some procedure or tequnique?
or other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To select multiple columns from a subquery, you'd normally use a join.  Now I'm not sure exactly how your tables relate, but something like this would be a good start:

```
SELECT  r.id
,       rl.reminder_header
,       rl.reminder_footer
FROM    reminders r
JOIN    reminder_levels AS rl
ON      rl.customer_id = r.customer_id
WHERE   rl.lookup =
        (
        SELECT  MAX(reminder_level_lookup) 
        FROM    reminders r2
        WHERE   r2.customer_id = r.customer_id
        )
```

Comment: +1 @Andomar, I was groping towards this when I saw your answer, although having worked it out (seen your version) I'm obliged to admit that I like the subquery version better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
with query as ( 
SELECT 
r.id,
(
        SELECT 
        r1::reminder_levels
        FROM reminder_levels AS rl
        WHERE rl.lookup =
        (
                SELECT MAX(reminder_level_lookup) 
                FROM reminders
                WHERE customer_id = r.customer_id
        )
) AS rec
FROM reminders AS r)
select id,
       (rec::reminder_levels).reminder_header,
       (rec::reminder_levels).reminder_footer
from query
```